# Can't change the mode of vi editor

Tags: bash, unix, console, vi, freebsd

When I try to leave an inserting mode

> :i

and press "Esc" key terminal put

> ^[

character in console and following run in inserting mode.

So I can't do something like:

> :wq

What happening?

```
:i 
Entering ex input mode.
*****/usr/home/example/example2/cron_task.sh^[
```

Comment: The mistake you are making is you are running the `:i` command, which is not what you want.

open vim, and then press ONLY i to start insert mode. After that you may press keys to start typing and press esc to exit the mode. Don't put the semicolon in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:i` <kbd>CR</kbd> is not the same command as `i`

To leave the latter, you enter: <kbd>ESC</kbd>

To leave the former, you enter: <kbd>CR</kbd>`.`<kbd>CR</kbd>